# Django : SimpleListFilter queryset

Tags: django, list, filter, admin

I have my model:

```
class Category(models.Model):  # family
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)

class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=_('family'))

class Essai_Temperature(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Material, verbose_name=_('name'))
```

I would like to have in the admin a list_filter with materials dependant of the family such when a family is selected (ceramic, Ni, Ti...), only materials that are related to the category are listed in filter options

admin :

```
class tri_nameFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('family') 
    parameter_name = 'family'

def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    allmat = set([c.category for c in Material.objects.all()])
    return [(c, c) for c in allmat]

def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    if self.value():
        return queryset.filter(name=self.value())
    else:
        return queryset

class Essai_TemperatureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_filter = (tri_nameFilter, 'name__name')
```

but I have an error when I click on a family

for example, if I click on 'Ni'

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Ni
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Please include the full traceback -- it tells us the exact line where the error is occurring. Otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: It is the line with : return queryset.filter(name=self.value))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `lookups` method, `c.category` is a `Category` instance, I would avoid using it in the lookups, and explicitly use the id and the name attributes.

```
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    allmat = set([c.category for c in Material.objects.all()])
    return [(c.id, c.name) for c in allmat]
```

The second problem is in your `queryset` method.

You are using the filter

```
return queryset.filter(name=self.value())
```

Here, the model is `Essai_Temperature`, and `name` is a foreign key to the material.  However you are providing a string `Ni` (the name of a category), instead of a `material` instance. That doesn't match, so you get the error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Ni
```

You want to filter on the category of the material, so you need to alter your query to:

```
return queryset.filter(name__category=self.value())
```

If you're not familiar with the double underscore notation used in `name__category`, then see the Django docs on [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: yes, thanks, It works but I would like to display in the filter list only the materials of the family. If i have only one material for the family : 'Ni', If i click on 'Ni',I want to display one material in the filter list on the right

Comment: I want that tri_nameFilter and 'name__name' are both dependent in the column 'Filter' ?

Comment: I'm not immediately sure how you would do that, list filters are not normally dependent on each other. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: the problem is that whatever the family of materials selected I have a list of all the materials of all families that is displayed in the column 'Filter'

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's how Django filters normally work, I'm not sure how you would change it to make one filter dependent on another.

Answer (score 0):

The way foreign keys are stored is through automatic fields(IDs). Since 'category' is a foreign field of 'material', when you make a record entry, the id of category is stored,not the actual name('Ni' etc), hence the error that its expecting an int and a string was given.

What you can do is, get IDs of 'Ni, ceramic' in a list and use it to filter material records using '__in'

Something like this:

```
category_ids_list= []
category_names_list = ['Ni', 'ceramic','Ti'] ## From your selected list from front end.
# Iterate through names and get IDs
for category_name in category_names_list:
    category_object = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
    category_ids_list.append(category_object.id)

Material.objects.filter(category__in=category_ids_list)
```